# floating point number system and geometric sum

Tags: real-analysis, summation

In the  floating point number system you can write  a random number x as the following:

$$ x= (-1)^s \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}d_i b^{-i}\right) \cdot 2^e$$
with $e \in \{e_{min},...,e_{max} \}, d_i \in \{0,...,b-1 \} $

For the mantissa holds then: $$ \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}d_i b^{-i} \leq \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(b-1) b^{-i} = (b-1) \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}b^{-i} \overset{!}{=} b(1-b^{-m}) $$

But the formula for the geometric sum would imply:$$ b \frac{1-b^{-m}}{1-b}$$

Do you see the mistake?

Comment: I found this on following site: https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~leykekhman/courses/MATH3795/Lectures/Lecture_2_Floating_point.pdf page 24

Comment: They state, that the result is: $b(1-b^{-m})$

Comment: Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction.

$$(b-1) \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}b^{-i} =(b-1)\ b \frac{1-b^{-m}}{1-b}= b(1-b^{-m}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see my mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct as stated; yours is wrong:

\begin{eqnarray}
(b-1)\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}b^{-i}
&=&
(b-1)\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\left(b^{-1}\right)^i
\\
&=&
(b-1)\frac{1-\left(b^{-1}\right)^m}{1-b^{-1}}
\\
&=&
b(b-1)\frac{1-\left(b^{-1}\right)^m}{b-1}
\\
&=&
b\left(1-b^{-m}\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you very much:)